# NavigateUrl binding and formatting issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have

```
<Hyperlink attachedProperty:HyperlinkExtensions.IsExternal="true">
    <Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
        <Binding Path="Name" StringFormat="http://anycoolsite.net/tag={0}" />
    </Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
    <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Path="Title" StringFormat="http://anycoolsite.net/tag={0}" />
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
</Hyperlink>
```

and an attached property for that

```
public class HyperlinkExtensions
{
    public static bool GetIsExternal(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsExternalProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsExternal(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsExternalProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExternalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsExternal", typeof(bool), typeof(HyperlinkExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsExternalChanged));

    private static void OnIsExternalChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var hyperlink = sender as Hyperlink;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
        else
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate -= Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
    }

    private static void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

When I try to get an url from e, I only have a bound *Name* part, which is in *{0}*.
How to get the formatted one (http://anycoolsite.net/anyboundname)?

For testblock text the binding and formatting works as expected

Comment: StringFormat is only used when the Binding's target property is of type string, which NavigateUri isn't. Use a Binding Converter instead.

Comment: @Clements Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

OK, changed my extension this way:

```
public class HyperlinkExtensions
{
    public static string GetUrlFormat(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(UrlFormatProperty);
    }

    public static void SetUrlFormat(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(UrlFormatProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlFormatProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UrlFormat", typeof(string), typeof(HyperlinkExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnUrlFormatChanged));

    private static void OnUrlFormatChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var hyperlink = sender as Hyperlink;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) args.NewValue))
        {
            hyperlink.NavigateUri = new Uri(string.Format((string) args.NewValue, hyperlink.NavigateUri));
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate -= Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
        }
        else
        {
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate -= Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
        }
    }


    private static void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Hyperlink attachedProperty:HyperlinkExtensions.UrlFormat="https://anycoolsite.com/products/{0}" ToolTip="Click to open in browser">
    <Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
        <Binding Path="ProductName"/>
    </Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
</Hyperlink>
```